# How can I check that a form field is prefilled correctly using capybara?

Tags: forms, rspec, capybara

I have a field with a proper label that I can fill in with capybara without a problem:

```
fill_in 'Your name', with: 'John'
```

I'd like to check the value it has before filling it in and can't figure it out.

If I add after the `fill_in` the following line:

```
find_field('Your name').should have_content('John')
```

That test fails, although the filling just before worked as I've verified by saving the page.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can use an *xpath query* to check if there's an `input` element with a particular value (e.g. 'John'):

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("//input[@value='John']")
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp for more info.

For perhaps a prettier way:

```
expect(find_field('Your name').value).to eq 'John'
```

EDIT: Nowadays I'd probably use have_selector

```
expect(page).to have_selector("input[value='John']")
```

If you are using the page object pattern(you should be!)

```
class MyPage < SitePrism::Page
  element :my_field, "input#my_id"

  def has_secret_value?(value)
    my_field.value == value
  end
end

my_page = MyPage.new

expect(my_page).to have_secret_value "foo"
```

Comment: Ah, I was missing the `.value` bit. Thanks!

Comment: I was having the same problem, but with a div rather than a form field. For anybody else having the same problem, use find_by_id().text rather than find_field().value. It took me *ages* to spot that value only worked on form fields…

Comment: The problem with the latter way is that it does not use Capybara's polling cycle and therefore will fail instantly if the field is set by longer-running JS code. The first way is to be preferred unless you are trying this on a statically generated form.

Comment: I think @fqxp has a better answer which uses RSpec Matchers and the new expectation syntax. From what I see in the documentation, `find_field` and other `Node::Finders` are used to find nodes and perform actions on them rather than expectation. Of course this is not a rule, but for something simple as this going with the inbuilt solution is a better idea. Just saying!

Comment: True, expect would be the preferred way now, however that syntax was released about a month after this question.

Comment: With **Minitest** the lines look like this: `assert has_xpath?("//input[@value='John']")` and `assert_equal 'John', find_field('Your name').value`

Comment: You could also use the form `find_field('field-name').value.should have_content('John')` if you don't want to match on the entire field value.

Answer (score 367):

Another pretty solution would be:

```
page.should have_field('Your name', with: 'John')
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_field('Your name', with: 'John')
```

respectively.

Also see the [reference](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_field%3F-instance_method).

*Note*: for disabled inputs, you'll need to add the option `disabled: true`.

Comment: Much better than the selected answer!

Comment: I would still prefer the selected answer because the error message shows you the expected and actual strings. This gives the unhelpful "expected field "my field" to return something" error. But this one does definitely read better and follows the page matcher API better. Upvotes all around!!!

Comment: This worked for me when using typeahead.js to verify the contents of the field, while the xpath matcher did not.

Comment: I think that happens because with that have_field capybara is waiting some time for that field before reporting failure.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn't actually confirm the value of the field, just the presence of the field regardless of value. I'm guessing it's a bug since the docs say it should filter based on value.

Comment: Passing in `with` definitely only returned true if the value matches, for me, which is the expected result.

Comment: Maybe the error message has been improved since the answer was first written, but I now get `expected […] but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters..` on an empty field which comes very close to a very nice error message.

Comment: If you're using poltergeist, this answer is best because it will keep checking until the configured timeout, so you don't need a bunch of lame sleeps in your specs.

Comment: One more thing to look out for - if you field is disabled, you must do `expect(page).to have_field('Your name', with: 'John', disabled: true)` for this to work.

Comment: This has the advantage of being DOM-agnostic. It works for other form fields like `textarea`.

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically want to test for a placeholder, use:

```
page.should have_field("some_field_name", placeholder: "Some Placeholder")
```

or:

```
expect(page).to have_field("some_field_name", placeholder: "Some Placeholder")
```

If you want to test the user-entered value:

```
page.should have_field("some_field_name", with: "Some Entered Value")
```

Answer (score 3):

If the field is a hidden one with an id of 'some_field', then you can use

```
expect(find("input#somefield", :visible => false).value).to eq 'John'
```

Comment: This is the best. Working long time with Capybara i had the best experiences with the find function and found it more practical to select controls by css-selectors and not by labels.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering how to do something slightly different: I wanted to test whether the field had *some* value (while making use of [Capybara's ability to re-test the matcher until it matches](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends)). It turns out that it's possible to use a "filter block" to do this:

```
expect(page).to have_field("field_name") { |field|
  field.value.present?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This the easiest way:

```
expect(page).to have_field("name", with: "your name")
<input type="text" id="name" />
```