# With Rails and Rspec, is there a way to see what page an action really takes you to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, assert

I have a rails test in which I go to a page and enter information, save the page (which takes me back one page), and attempt to come back to see if the data is still there. I am hitting a wall, but suspect that if I could see what is on the page, I could discern what when wrong or how to adapt my assertions. Is there a way to visualize/breakpoint/curl that page that test is actually encountering? Everything I assert is coming back false.

```
it "Emergency Contact step saves data submitted" do
  click_link "Register online"
  click_link "Emergency Contacts"
  fill_in "Contact 1 Name", :with => "1 name"
  fill_in "Contact 1 Phone", :with => "123.456.7890"
  click_button "Save"
  click_link "Emergency Contacts"
  assert page.has_content?("1 name")
  assert page.has_content?("123.456.7890") 
end
```

Comment: @dbugger `puts response.body` fails for me, but @Unixmonkey's  `puts page.html` works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique I use after a page transition is to check the current path (route) against a known one like this:

```rb
assert_equal page.current_path, new_page_path
# or
assert_equal page.current_path, "/things/new"
```

Another way to debug could be to look at the contents of `page.html` like

```rb
puts page.html
```

Or use capybara's `save_and_open_page` method, which save the HTML of the current page to your Rails app's `tmp` directory and opens that in a browser.

Comment: `puts page.html` is exactly what I needed. I am on the right page, and the data is present. Apparently, I am using the wrong assert to test for it.

This was in my response: `<div title="Contact_1_name_div">
  <label for="emer_con_person_1_name">Contact 1 Name</label><br />
  <input type="text" value="1 name" />
</div>`

Comment: For the record, the correct assert is `expect(page).to have_field('Contact 1 Name', with: '1 name')`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503802/how-can-i-check-that-a-form-field-is-prefilled-correctly-using-capybara/16584670#16584670